# Is there a known problem with array of objects ? when assigning a value e.g. to a[0].name, the element a[1].name gets also the same value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm assigning a value to an array element, e.g. array1[0].name, then array1[1].name, array1[2].name,... gets also the value assigned only to array1[0].name.

The following code, is very symplified:

the following object is passed over to this function as an argument, and has the structure:

```
var reccurenceObject = {
   howOften:,
}
```

the code:

```
for (var j = 0; j < cycle; j++) {                     
      eventsArray[j].howOften = reccurenceObject[j].howOften; 
}
```

Any idea why elements with different index are getting the values also ?

Thank you for any Helo.

Dani

Comment: You are probably doing shallow copies somewhere in the code. If you want further help, please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `recurrenceObject[j]` where `j` is a number `0 <= j < cycle` indicates that `recurrenceObject` is A) an *array* of objects or B) an Object with numerical keys. However, `recurrenceObject` only has one key according to your description, which isn't numerical but instead called `"howOften"`. If that isn't the issue then please provide some more code as @vicbyte has already suggested.

Comment: I have found the answer for my issue. My issue was answered implicitly with issue: "Declaring array of objects" nr.: 69. I had to initialise the array with: .push({});.